# Is there a way to tell ReSharper that a property is not null if (and only if) another property is true?

Tags: c#, resharper

With the following result being returned from a method:

```
public class MyFunctionResult {
    bool Success { get; }

    [CanBeNull] // ????
    SomeObj Result { get; }

    private MyFunctionResult() {};

    public static Success([NotNull] SomeObj result) {
        return new MyFunctionResult {
           Success = true,
           Result = result
        };
    }

    public static Failure() {
        return new MyFunctionResult {
            Success = false
        };
    }
}

[NotNull]
MyFunctionResult MyFunction() { ... }

DoSomething([NotNull] SomeObj obj) { ... }
```

how can I tell ReSharper to warn me about possible null assignment in case of

```
var result = MyFunction();
DoSomething(result.Result);
```

but not to worry about

```
var result = MyMethod();
if(result.Success) {
    DoSomething(result.Result);
}
```

How do I annotate the dependency that if (and only if) Success is true, Result is NotNull?

Comment: This is very similar to a `Result` class that I wrote, and I had exactly the same problem. Never did work out how to do it... One difference in my class is that my `Result` property throws an `InvalidOperationException` if `Success` is false, but that doesn't help with this unfortunately.

Comment: I've never used Resharper, but C# has nullable reference types now, and [`[MemberNotNullWhen]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.membernotnullwhenattribute?view=net-5.0) is the attribute you'd be using, if you were using C#'s nullable reference types, rather than Resharper's own static null analysis attributes. Have you considered migrating?

Comment: Sadly, `[MemberNoNullWhen]` is not available in .net Standard :( There's a NuGet package that might work, though.

Answer (score 1):

There is no appropriate annotation in ReSharper